# Limiting Reactants without a given mass

Tags: reaction-mechanism, combustion

This is a question I have for Chemistry homework, but I don't understand how to solve it without a given mass. I narrowed the choices down (see below ***_***) I know a limiting reactant well limits the reaction (so if there are 2 reactants) and the react left is the excess reactant.

I thought Propane would be the limiting reactant because the oxygen is in excess (though that was incorrect).

Then, I though Oxygen would be the limiting reactant (naturally) since its a combustion reaction (though that is incorrect).

Determine whether each reaction depends on a limiting reactant. Explain why or why not and identify the limiting reactant. (Select all that apply.)

(c) Propane (C3H8) burns in excess oxygen to produce carbon dioxide and water.

Yes, one reactant is naturally limiting.
Yes, there are two reactants.
No, all reactants are in excess.
No, there is only one reactant.
propane
oxygen
carbon dioxide
water
Not enough information to identify which is the limiting reactant.

---

Yes, one reactant is naturally limiting.
Yes, there are two reactants.
No, all reactants are in excess.
propane
oxygen
Not enough information to identify which is the limiting reactant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would need information about how much of each reactant you have when conducting this. edit: "Excess" is the key word here; so it hints that Oxygen is NOT the limiting reagent. Considering how combustion reactions are structured, the answer seems to be the other reactant here.

Comment: This was actually a 3-part question, but I figured out the first 2 parts. (a) Potassium chlorate decomposes to form potassium chloride and oxygen. (No, there is only one reactant.) (b) Silver nitrate and hydrochloric acid react to produce silver chloride and nitric acid. (Yes, there are two reactant, but not enough information to tell). I wasn't given any masses for either a or b, yet it was still possible to determine the answer. Using this, can you determine an answer for c, or should I saw there isn't enough information?

Comment: Because it says excess, can I assume that oxygen isn't the limiting reactant? And what does the term "naturally limiting mean?

Comment: Oh snap. I totally missed "excess". Whenever you see that it basically means there is an unlimited amount of that reactant. My apologies!
As for "naturally limiting reactant", I'd take it to just be a syntax modification to deal with the fact that you do in fact have excess Oxygen, I've never heard of a reactant being "naturally limiting" before.

Comment: Reading the question multiple times again, for "naturally limiting reactant", it is probably a corresponding answer to selecting one of the chemicals also listed. i.e. Yes, one reactant is naturally limiting (because there is excess Oxygen), and then you specify that the reactant would be propane.

Comment: My homework is online and allows for 3 tries before I miss it completely. I used my first try on putting Propane would be the limiting reactant. I used my second my saying Propane because it was naturally limiting (I didn't understand what naturally limiting meant though)